# Katta in production environment

Tags: lucene, distributed, scalable, katta

According to the [website](http://katta.sourceforge.net/) Katta is a scalable, failure tolerant, distributed, indexed, data storage.

I would like to know if it is ready to be deployed into production environment. Anyone already using it and has advices? Any pitfalls? Recommendations? Testimonials? Please share.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://katta.sourceforge.net/about/powered-by-katta has few. I also would like to hear first hand experience though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have tried using katta and for what its worth - found it very stable, relatively easy to manage (as compared to managing plain vanilla lucene)

Only pitfall I can think of is lack of realtime updates - when we tested it (about 9-10 months back) update meant, updating index using a separate process (hadoop job or what have you...) and replacing the live index, this was a deal-breaker for us.

If you are looking into distributed lucene you should really tryout [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) or [Solandra](https://github.com/tjake/solandra)